# Dataframe poner en filas los valores de un cierto rango de columnas

Tags: python, pandas

A continuación muestro un trozo de un dataframe donde cada fila representa un usuario `subject_id` y donde cada usuario tiene 72 `values` puestos en columnas (0 a la 71)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero conseguir es que cada fila contenga 24 `values` puestos en columnas,por lo que ahora cada usuario `subject_id` generará 3 filas. La primera fila contendrá los `values` de la columna 0 a la 23, la segunda los de la columna 24 a la 47 y la tercera los de la 48 a la 71.

```
____________________________________________________
| subject_id |    0   |    1   |    2  ...   23    |
|__________________________________________________|
|    10      |   160  |  154   |  162  ...  143    |
|    10      |   95   |  123   |  135  ...  98     |
|    10      |   107  |  150   |  100.5...  122    |
|    1000    |   85   |  85    |  84   ...  101    |
|    1000    |   160  |  164   |  162  ...  133    |
|    1000    |   110  |  115   |  99   ...  154.5  |
|   ...........................................    |
|__________________________________________________|
```

A ver si alguien puede echarme una mano. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Una pregunta para ver si te puedo ayudar: ¿Cómo estas poblando la tabla? ¿ Con una consulta a una base de datos o a través de otro método? Ideal si puedes incorporar el código que pobla la tabla.

Comment: @EduardoMunizaga Es una consulta a base de datos pero se le han hecho bastantes modificaciones al dataframe hasta tener esta forma. No me había expresado bien en la pregunta, lo que se muestra es un fragmento del dataframe que contiene 19215 filas y 72 columnas. Bastaría con hacer el ejemplo para un `subject_id` y que se pudiera aplicar al resto, o para que sea más cómodo un ejemplo más sencillo con menos columnas.

Comment: La pregunta estaba clara solo quería saber cómo poblabas la tabla. Yo creo que esto se podría resolver con una consulta SQL adecuada si se me ocurre algo te aviso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me ocurre una forma un poco rara, no muy ortodoxa:

- Extrae los valores de tu dataframe (`df.values`) lo que te da un array numpy (de N filas y 72 columnas)
- Usa `numpy.reshape()` para redistribuir esos mismos valores en otras dimensiones (usando N*3 filas, y 24 columnas)
- Crea un nuevo dataframe a partir de esa matriz, usando como índice el que tenía el dataframe original, pero con cada elemento repetido tres veces (cosa que puedes obtener con `numpy.repeat()`.

Al final esas tres cosas se hacen en una sola lína.

Ejemplo. Partimos de estos datos (que genero al azar):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(5, 72))
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.index.name = "subject_id"
```

[image: Dataframe entrada]

Y hacemos:

```
nuevo = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape((len(df)*3, 24)),
                     index=np.repeat(df.index, 3))
```

obteniendo:

[image: Dataframe salida]

Comment: No muy ortodoxo pero efectivo ;). Por cierto, no se corresponden los valores de los dataframes `df` y `nuevo`, probablemente porque has ejecutado otra vez el código de generación de `df` y te ha variado respecto al inicial (otros valores random). Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: @jsdj21 Bien visto! Acabo de regenerar las imágenes.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptualmente el problema se podría expresar como:

- Generamos tres `dataframes` con `subject_id` y los 24 valores correspondientes
- Renombramos las 24 columnas con el mismo nombre en los tres `dataframes`
- Hacemos un append de los `dataframes`

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [20,7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]], columns=['subjet_id', '0', '1','2','3', '4', '5'])
print (df)

   subjet_id  0  1  2   3   4   5
0         10  1  2  3   4   5   6
1         20  7  8  9  10  11  12

newcolumns = ['subjet_id', '0', '1'] 
df1 = df[['subjet_id','0','1']]
df1.columns = newcolumns

df2 = df[['subjet_id','2','3']]
df2.columns = newcolumns

df3 = df[['subjet_id','4','5']]
df3.columns = newcolumns

newdf = df1.append(df2.append(df3)).sort_values('subjet_id').reset_index(drop=True)

print(newdf)

   subjet_id   0   1
0         10   1   2
1         10   3   4
2         10   5   6
3         20   7   8
4         20   9  10
5         20  11  12
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta